# Compare a character of a string with another character of a string

Tags: c++

I was given a task to write a simple post-fix to infix program.

The idea is that a user gives me an expression, say:

> userInput = "(2)1+5*(2-1)"

I was planning to use another string to define my character priority through the index of said character, say:

> charPrio= "()-+/*^)"

My idea was to iterate through the `userInput` with a for loop and then make the necessary comparisons on the `charPrio` using the character positions.

Something more or less like:

```
for (int i =0 ; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
      if (userInput[i]==charPrio[0]){
             //do something
      }
}
```

When using the if I get problems when doing the comparison, for the iteration `0` I get that `userInput[0]` = ""

Ideally, I would want to enter the if in this iteration given the `userInput` above.

But it doesn't, to my understanding indexes in c++ start at 0 so I believe that I am doing a comparison of `userInput[0] == charPrio[0]` which should be `"("=="("`.

Honestly, I'm not quite sure if I am using the strings correctly, or if there is a better way to do this.

I tried using constants for the comparison:

```
if (userInput[i]== "(" )
```

but I get an error saying I can't use different data types (operand types are incompatible (char and const char))

Is there a better way to compare characters of a string, or am I using the indexes wrong?

Comment: Character literals use single quotes, `'('`.

Comment: `for(for (int i =0 ; i < userInput.length(); i++)` why two for?

Comment: *I was given a the task to write a simple post-fix to infix program.* -- You should be using a stack data structure for this, and not what you are doing now with string comparisons.  This is getting close to an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/), but you did mention the `X` part briefly, so I give you credit.  It's the `Y` that looks convoluted.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the actual topic of the chapter in the textbook you're using for "learning C++" whose practice program is "to write a simple post-fix to infix program"? There can be several different approaches, and usually you're expected to use the one that's the chapter's topic, so knowing what it is can help in pointing you to the correct approach.